# Why non-zero finite variance in chebyshev inequality.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I read Chebyshev's inequality from certain places. The statement is:
Let X be a random variable with a finite mean denoted as $\mu$ and a finite non-zero variance, which is denoted as $\sigma^2$, for any real number, $k>0$
$$P(|X-\mu|\geq k) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{k^2}.$$
My question is why "finite non zero variance". Isn't it still fine if variance is zero or infinite?

Comment: Just reading it, seems like it would be fine., just not saying much.  0 variance would be a constant random variable (Up to a measure 0 set),  so both the LHS and RHS will be 0.

Comment: yes, I also think it should be fine with zero varaince and for infinite variance, I think mean will also be infinite which might create problem, but still I want to know complete truth with surety

Comment: The wikipedia article defines the inequality as$$P(|X-\mu|\geq \sigma k) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$...which would require $\sigma>0$.

Comment: Right @Joe, I also realized that.

Comment: the inequality would be still right if the variance is zero or infinite. If the variance is zero it means that the random variable $X$ is degenerated, that is, that $P(X=\mu)=1$. When the variance is infinite the inequality trivially holds, as $P(|X-\mu|\geqslant k)\leqslant 1$ for any chosen $k\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @masacroso, if variance is infinite, what will happen to mean?, I mean $|X-\mu|$ might not be defined.

Comment: @UserA this is not right, it is possible that $|X-\mu|$ is well-defined but it variance doesn't exists